# .htaccess url rewriting is working but not the redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I'm working on a local server on an `html/php` application and I'm trying to use the Apache url rewrite module without success

The application was stored in `./Compta/index.php`.  I have to an `.htaccess` file in `./Compta/.htaccess`

I would like to only use a rewritten url like :`http://localhost/Compta/Test/`

instead of : `http://localhost/Compta/index.php?page=test`

and redirect users if they try to go to the old url

The .htaccess file contains :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([[:alnum:]]*)/$   /Compta/index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([[:alnum:]]*)$   /Compta/index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([[:alnum:]]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/Compta/%1/ [L,R=301]
```

When I go to `http://localhost/Compta/Test/` the following line is working and my code includes in a div the content of `test.php` :

```
RewriteRule ^([[:alnum:]]*)/$   /Compta/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

When I go to `http://localhost/Compta/Test` the following line is working but in firefox the url is rewritten to `http://localhost/Compta/index.php?page=Test` and this is not happening with `http://localhost/Compta/Test2`; the url isn't rewritten.

```
RewriteRule ^([[:alnum:]]*)$   /Compta/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

To fix this and to redirect the old url I added these lines :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([[:alnum:]]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/Compta/%1/ [L,R=301]
```

But this is not working and when I go to `http://localhost/Compta/index.php?page=Test` the url isn't rewritten to `http://localhost/Compta/Test/`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution with .htaccess but i found one with php so i added the following lines in top of my php files :

```
        if(preg_match("/\/Compta\/index\.php\?page=([[:alnum:]]*)/",@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$page)&&!empty($page[1]))
        {
            $new_url = "/Compta/";
            switch (strtolower($page[1])) {
                case "test":
                    $new_url = $new_url."Test/";
                    break;
                case "test2":
                    $new_url = $new_url."Test2/";
                    break;
                default:break;
            }
            header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently", false, 301); 
            header("Location: ".$new_url);
            exit;
        }
```

I test if the url begin with "/Compta/index.php?page=" AND if there is a parameter for "page"
Then I initialise the variable which contain the new url
Switch the content of my parameter I modify the new url
and then I make the redirection to my new url :)